# Drag Drop Between two Grid Views on multiple forms

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

So i have a main form then multiple windows with data grid views in.

I want to be able to swap data to and from the main window to the child windows and vice versa.

I have on my main form:

```
private Rectangle dragBoxFromMouseDown;
    private object valueFromMouseDown;

    private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hittestInfo = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (hittestInfo.RowIndex != -1 && hittestInfo.ColumnIndex != -1)
        {
            valueFromMouseDown = dataGridView1.Rows[hittestInfo.RowIndex];
            if (valueFromMouseDown != null)
            {
                Size dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;
                dragBoxFromMouseDown = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X - (dragSize.Width / 2), e.Y - (dragSize.Height / 2)), dragSize);
            }
        }
        else
            dragBoxFromMouseDown = Rectangle.Empty;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (dragBoxFromMouseDown != Rectangle.Empty && !dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y))
            {
                DragDropEffects dropEffect = dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(valueFromMouseDown, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then on my child forms:

```
        private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y);

        if (hit.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(hit.RowIndex, e.Data.GetData(typeof(Objects.Amazon.PoDetail)));
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(e.Data.GetData(typeof(Objects.Amazon.PoDetail)));
        }
    }
```

Obviously, it fails at the e.Data.GetData as its getting the data from the current datagridview in the child form.

I can't think of a way of passing the data between the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How that can be possible.  dragdrop data is of same type you have passed in DoDragDrop method. thus it is of **DataGridViewRow** type. So that should be-

```
object dropData = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow));
```